# MySQL : How To Create Trigger on Database for Track

Tags: mysql

Could anyone please let me know how to fire trigger when stored procedure, Table is created, Deleted or modified?

Comment: No idea where you are coming from ,'A trigger is a named database object that is associated with a table, and that activates when a particular event occurs for the table. '...'A trigger is defined to activate when a statement inserts, updates, or deletes rows in the associated table' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/triggers.html In othere words you cannot fire a trigger directly.

Comment: I want Insert log for whom Alter, Create , delete table Or procedure. Trigger on Whole Database not Table.

Comment: ***@HitendraDeriya***: configure at database server level for logs. contact your db admin.

Comment: @RavinderReddy How to Track All Database Changes in MYSQL?

Comment: _**@HitendraDeriya**_: You better read article on [_MySQL Server Logs_](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-logs.html)